# Is it possible to install and run Thunar 1.5.1 in Lubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, upgrade, lubuntu, thunar, tabs

I hear that **a new Thunar (with tabs!!) is ready** - see [this](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/11/install-thunar-with-tabs-support-in.html).

I have added the PPA and run the update and upgrade commands but I still have Thunar 1.2.3

In Synaptic, Thunar looks ready for upgrade:

[image]

It asks to uninstall some XFCE stuff that I might hope to reinstall later

[image]

but then something is fishy

[image]

Is this new version limited to the Xfce desktop?

Also, now, when I try Update Manager, I get this:

[image]

and

[image]

...unless I remove the xubuntu-dev/xfce-4.12 PPAs.

So, removing Thunar in Synaptic and all that seems related to it, and then adding those PPAs, and trying to install Thunar, the following info emerges:

[image]

What is to be done?

Comment: Do you see those packages in synaptics: `libthunarx-2-0` and `thunar-data` and which versions are available? If you see the right versions, you should be able to mark them for upgrade too.

Comment: The ppas are for Xubuntu, but try the following and see if it works: remove all your xfce material and ppas to get a fresh start, restart then install xubuntu-desktop, restart and then add both the xfce 4.10 and 4.12 ppas, as it is noted you need **both** ppas at [Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/~xubuntu-dev/+archive/xfce-4.12). Then update and upgrade and the new Thunar should be available, whether you are running an xfce session or not.

Comment: @Mik: trying to avoid xubuntu-desktop for now, it comes with **huge** amount of other dependencies but in the and maybe i'll do it. from my experience, though, lubuntu works on top of xubuntu desktop but the other way round not so well

Comment: @cipricus Were you using both ppas before?

Comment: @Mik: did not, just when trying to install the new thunar that was the condition. after adding them updating the system gave those error messages and had to remove them. using xubuntu would solve it: for thunar is the main filemanager there and desktop manager too. but your solution might work

Comment: @cipricus You can use --no-install-recommends when installing xubuntu-desktop to get the very minimum files necessary, but you may be then missing some you may want.

Comment: @Mik: is that `sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends`?

Comment: @cipricus yes, `sudo apt-get install xubuntu-desktop --no-install-recommends`. To simulate it, first put `-s` after `apt-get`.

Comment: thnx. but would not try it for a a while. keep in touch

Comment: @Mik: it works. the idea is already clear in the link from the question: Latest Thunar needs the latest  Xfce4, that a simple installation of Xfce in Lubuntu 12.04 would not bring, so adding its ppa is necessary (http://www.webupd8.org/2012/05/install-xfce-410-in-xubuntu-1204.html); after that the new Thunar's ppa may be installed (http://www.webupd8.org/2012/11/install-thunar-with-tabs-support-in.html). After `sudo apt-get upgrade` and logging out and back in the new Thunar can be used in Lubuntu 12.04. Would you care making an answer out of that and get the bounty or you prefer that I do it?

Comment: removing all xfce related stuff before this was not necessary, but first of all i have installed xubuntu-desktop in synaptic, that is with the older version of xfce, and then upgraded that from the PPA

Comment: @cipricus glad you got it installed; I'll do a summary of my comments (particularly the first one) about installing xubuntu-desktop and then the ppas.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After several discussions in the comments, it was shown that the essentials of my first comment was correct and installing `xubuntu-desktop` and then the PPAs and then upgrading enabled `Thunar` to be installed and available in Lubuntu, and not just for the Xfce session.

Firstly, the ppas are designed for Xubuntu 12.04, as noted at [Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/~xubuntu-dev/+archive/xfce-4.12), so it may be easier to install `Xubuntu-desktop` and then upgrade that:

```
sudo apt-get install xubuntu-desktop
```

If you wish to get the very minimum amount of packages you could use the `--no-install-recommends` flag after `xubuntu-desktop`.

As noted at [Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/~xubuntu-dev/+archive/xfce-4.12), it is important to note that on 12.04 both the [Xfce 4.10 ppa](https://launchpad.net/~xubuntu-dev/+archive/xfce-4.10) and the [Xfce 4.12 ppa](https://launchpad.net/~xubuntu-dev/+archive/xfce-4.12) needs to be installed.

Install the 4.10 ppa first with

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xubuntu-dev/xfce-4.10
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Then logout and login again (in your normal Lubuntu session) and install the next PPA with

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xubuntu-dev/xfce-4.12
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Now logout and login again (in your normal Lubuntu session) and `Thunar` will be able to be used in a normal Lubuntu session and not just in an Xfce session.

This [article](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/05/install-xfce-410-in-xubuntu-1204.html) and [this one](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/11/install-thunar-with-tabs-support-in.html) contain information for updating a full Xubuntu 12.04 LTS install and may also be useful, but, as I have shown, the steps are different in Lubuntu 12.04.